# Need apache to proxy subdirectory to another service

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, proxy, port

I have a website running on Apache, at 192.168.1.90:80 for xxxxxxxxx.com
I also have a reddit instance running at 192.168.1.90:8001 for reddit.local

I have been trying to proxy the url xxxxxxxx.com/reddit to the port 8001
such that someone visits xxxxxxxx.com/reddit/r/games they should be served the same page as when i locally visit reddit.local/r/games

I dont want the url to reflect the port 8001 to the viewer.

How can I get this done, I am not that good with Apache .htaccess file and is a noob at that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the httpd.conf file, you can use mod_proxy (see [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)). If not, you can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/proxy.html). If you need help using either of them, post the config you've tried and ask a specific question about that config.